# Are the groups $(\mathbb{R} \!\,, +)$ and $(\mathbb{R} \!\,^*,\dot{\,} \!\,)$ isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory

I have an exercise to do and I don't understand how to solve it. It states:

> Determine if the groups $(\mathbb{R} \!\,, +)$ and $(\mathbb{R} \!\,^*,\cdot{\,} \!\,)$ are isomorphic and to justify the answer.

I am not very good at this, but I would like a full demonstration.

$ \mathbb{R}^* = \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\} $

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you thought about torsion elements?

Answer (score 9):

$\textbf{Hint:} \:\:(-1)^2 = 1^2$

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to see an entire explanation.

Comment: You'll have to figure it out yourself.

Comment: He gave you a property about one of the groups. Start by finding out which one he was talking about, and then check that this property would be conserved by a group isomorphism. Now, if you can prove this property doesn't hold in the other group, you've proven they are not isomorphic.

Comment: I understood what you told me, but I would really appreciate a full answer in order to understand the full judgement.

Comment: If you understood what Arthur and xaviermo2 are saying then you should be able to do this problem. xaviermo2 has essentially outlined the entire solution. Please put some effort into solving the problem *by yourself* - you won't learn anything if they just spit out the entire solution for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not very sure how to start and how to solve this one. Should I make assume that there is an isomorphism and to find out that $(-1)^2 =1^2$ which makes my groups un-insomorphs

Comment: $\phi(a+a)=\phi(a)\phi(a)$ right? So what's $\phi$ gonna map to $-1$? (now finish yourself)

Comment: I assume that $Exists f:R->R* so f(x+y)=f(x)*f(y), any x,y e ∈ R $
$For x=-1 and y=-1, I get f(-1+-1)=f(-1)*f(-1) => f(-2) = 2f(-1)$ Maybe I am too dumb

Comment: Learner: Since when can one replace $f(-1)f(-1)$ by $2f(-1)$?

Comment: That's true, I am too sleepy, it's 2 AM here.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding neat comment of @anon, note that: $$t(\mathbb R,+)=\{0\}\neq\{\pm1\}=t(\mathbb R^*,\cdot)$$ So you have different elements in both group which satisfy $x^n=id|_G$ where $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Dear Babak...I'm facing the daily (anonymous) downvotes again :-(